# Issue with terminal and localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, localhost

I'm following [this blog tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWHGQfzfHxI) to help complete an assignment (I'm doing a HTML/CSS/Javascript bootcamp, the assignment is for a functioning blog with certain characteristics), but there are several passages using the terminal, with which I have 0 familiarity. Around the 6th minute of the video, it shows to set up the server and than to check its functionality via both the terminal and the browser. His result is a blank page (as it apparently should be), whilst I keep gettin "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory". Having no prior experience with the terminal, I don't really know what to do. I tried to follow various suggestions from other Stackoverflow similar questions but nothing works. I've been stuck here for hours and I'd really like to go ahead. As you could guess, I'm very inexperienced.

Please find below the screenshot of my VS code and of the problem.
[image: VS Code screenshot][image]

Comment: Typo. home.html isn't in the public directory where you've told the program to read it from

Comment: Look at the error message. It is looking in your public folder but your home.html file is not under your public folder.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! I know I'm dumb and it was a stupid (and time-wasting) mistake, but I'm still learning for a reason! :D Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As both Quentin and ddcastrodd correctly noticed, I misplaced the files around the folder. My bad! As is most of the time. :D